# html2canvas text alignment is off

Tags: html, html2canvas

I'm using html2canvas to allow users to download a div element to their local files as an image.
What they are saving is an image with dynamic text on top of it that changes based on their user input (this whole div becomes one image).

The saving part works, and users can save the div as an image to their local files. However, the dynamic text moves downward and the image looks off because of it.

I tried to make changes to html2canvas code based on someone's solution on github, but it didn't work and I reset this code to the original.

Is this a common problem that others have faced? How do I solve this problem without hard-coding the solution (moving the dynamic text up on the web application so when it moves downward when saving, it looks how it's supposed to look)?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are also using jspdf along with html2canvas ? You are probably using a font that is not part of jspdf defaults. You can try adding your font (https://www.devlinpeck.com/content/jspdf-custom-font) or convert the content to a default supported font before generating the canvas, then revert the content to the initial font. The issue with the latter is users will see the font shift, but you could cover the page with a cool loader.

Comment: I'm facing this issue either: Vertical alignment of text does not match the appearance in the browser's view. A solution would be very welcome. I'm using html2canvas along with jspdf, however the alignment is wrong in the canvas being rendered, before inserting it into the PDF.